# mac osx copy bootable startvolume works but keeps filesystem

Tags: macos, partitioning, ssd, filesystems, superduper

He there,

i have a macbook air with one ssd hdd that is unfortunetly formatted as journal extended case sensitive.

so i have an external hdd where i copied my whole startvolume bootable with the tool "supderDuper!" and it works fine, now when i format the ssd to the correct filesystem ( journal extended not case sensitive) it successfully formats it, when i now try to copy back with superDuper it works but keeps the old file system so its useless,

how to have the ssd with system on it and new Filesystem?
anybody has an idea ?

forany help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search, and it seems the answer can be found here:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/18610586#18610586

Hope that helps.

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged on StackExchanged sites. Please elaborate your answer by providing the main points from the link you provided which are relevant to the problem and you can then say "refer to ..." and link the site as a secondary reference.